# Sed or Awk or Perl substitution in a sentence

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, sed

I need to make a substitution using **Sed** or other program. I have these patterns `&lt;ehh&gt;` `&lt;mmm&gt;` `&lt;mhh&gt;` repeated at the beginning of a sentences and I need to substitute for nothing.

I am trying this:

```
echo "$line" | sed 's/&lt;[a-zA-z]+&gt;//g'
```

But I get the same result, nothing changes. Anyone can help?

Thank you!

Comment: echo "&lt;ehh&gt; this is test" | sed 's/&lt;ehh&gt;//g'

Comment: @anubhava this is the value "&lt;ahh&gt; here the sentence"
"

Comment: You have `ahh` in string but matching `ehh`

Comment: That is true, sorry! But if I have another pattern like "&lt;mmm&gt; ", can I make something like OR to the Sed instruction?

Comment: Don't know wich version of sed you're using, but to use regex on my Gnu sed 4.2.1 I have to add the -r option before the command: `echo "&lt;eeh&gt; this is test" | sed -r 's/&lt;[a-z]+&gt;//g'
 this is test
`

Comment: Looks like first problem is the range you have `[a-zA-z]` should be `[a-zA-Z]` and the `+` needs to be escaped: `sed 's/&lt;[a-zA-Z]\+&gt;//g'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me, for the test file

```
&lt;ahh&gt; test
&lt;mmm&gt;test 1
```

the following

```
sed 's/^&lt;[a-zA-Z]\+&gt;//g' testfile
```

produces

```
 test
test 1
```

which seems to be what you want. Note that for basic regular expressions, you use `\+` whereas for extended regular expressions, you use `+` (and need to use the `-r` switch for sed).

NB: I added a `^`to the check since you said: at the beginning of the line.

Comment: I think its probably the lack of backslash that was the problem.

Comment: Actually, `\+` is not part of basic regular expressions, it is an extension provided by GNU sed. Try `sed --posix 's/^&lt;[a-zA-Z]\+&gt;//g' file` (on GNU sed) and you will see that it doesn't work. The POSIX standard way of specifying _one or more matches_ is `\{1,\}`.

Comment: @TomFenech does `{n,m}` work for all posix sed's though. There doesn't seem to be any indication in the man page that it does.The way i have done it if `+` is missing is to just type the character first `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*`

Comment: @JID `\{n,m\}` is mentioned in the [POSIX regex spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xbd/re.html)

Comment: @JID I haven't personally tried _all seds_ but as far as I understand, any POSIX-compliant version of sed using BRE mode should work with that syntax. If the version of sed has an ERE mode too, then I guess it's supposed to follow the ERE spec in that mode.

Comment: Not all seds will support enabling ERE metachars by putting a backslash in front of them (e.g. the default sed on Solaris won't) but doing that for some subset of ERE metachars IS now part of POSIX for BREs so it'll work with most seds. I've no idea why POSIX didn't include `+` in that subset. Note that for portability across locales you should use `[[:alpha:]]` instead of `[a-zA-Z]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '&lt;ehh&gt; &lt;mmm&gt; &lt;mhh&gt;blabla bla' | \
sed '^Js/^\([[:space:]]*\&lt;[a-zA-Z]\{3\}\&gt;\)\{1,\}//'
```

- remove all starting occurence of your pattern (including heading space)
- I escape `&` to be sure due to sed meaning of this character in pattern (work without on my AIX)
- I don't use `g` because it remove several occurence of full pattern and there is only 1 begin (`^`) and use a multi occurence counter with group instead `\(\)\{1,\}`

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to get the last parameter from lines like this:

```
&lt;ahh&gt; test
&lt;mmm&gt;test 1
```

You can do:

```
awk -F\; '/^&lt;[[:alpha:]]+&gt/ {print $NF}' <<< "$line"
 test
test 1
```

It will search for pattern `&lt;[[:alpha:]]+&gt` and print last field on line, separated by `;`